# While checking if brackets are balanced, I am getting incorrect result (i.e., I know input string is balanced, but output is unbalanced)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newly studying data structures and algos. Im having trouble understanding why when implementing a Stack and using it to check if brackets are balanced, I am not getting the desired output (i.e. the input string is balanced but im getting the string is unbalanced).

```
class Stack(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()    

def isMatched(brackets):
    opening = ('(', '[','{')
    closing = (')', ']', '}')
    stack = Stack()

    for char in brackets:
        if char in opening:
            stack.push(char)
        elif char in closing:
            if stack.isEmpty or char != stack.pop():
                #print('The brackets currently in the stack are: {}'.format(char), sep = ', ') 
                return False
        elif char not in opening and closing:
            raise ValueError('Unknown character {char}'.format(char=char))

    if not stack.isEmpty():
        return False
    return True


string = "[]()"
print(string, "-", "Balanced" if isMatched(string) else "Unbalanced")
```

Comment: Presumably by `stack.isEmpty` you mean `stack.isEmpty()`

Comment: `elif char not in opening and closing` isn't what you meant either

Comment: @leafcudde The correct syntax of the ```elif``` @khelwood is referring to is:

```elif not char in opening and not char in closing:```

Comment: @khelwood Thanks for calling out my errors. Total brainfart

Comment: @fendall No problem. Always very happy to point out other people's errors.

Comment: You're only ever putting opening brackets onto the stack, then you're popping them off and comparing them to closing brackets. `[` does not equal `]`.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
if stack.isEmpty or ...
```

`stack.isEmpty` is effectively always true. You need to *call* the method: `stack.isEmpty()`.

Second:

```
elif char not in opening and closing:
```

The `and closing` part is also effectively always true, but in this case it is irrelevant because you already know at this point that `char` is not in `closing`. You should omit `and closing` entirely.

Third:

```
... or char != stack.pop():
```

`char` can never be equal to `stack.pop()` because at this point you know that `char` is a closing bracket, and `stack` only contains opening brackets. You need some logic associating each closing bracket with its opening counterpart.